# Many-to-One Subclass Foreign Key

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 tables event & location in the public schema. I have two tables in the 'other' schema which inherit from the public tables. There are 4 classes that mimic this setup (Event, Location, OtherEvent, & OtherLocation). I'm trying to use Hibernate to persist the OtherEvent & Other Location.

Every Event has 1+ Locations. A Location is meaningless with an Event.

If I create an OtherEvent and add an OtherLocation to it and try to save it, hibernate inserts the OtherEvent into other.event & hibernate inserts the OtherLocation into other.location (including the event_id).
Then hibernate tries to do: UPDATE public.location set event_id=? where location=?
This fails because I don't have permission on public.location. How can I prevent it from doing this update? Or change it so it does the update on the other.location table.

I tried modifying public.hbm.xml and changing:

```
<bag name="locations">
```

to

```
<bag name="locations" inverse="true">
```

This doesn't do the update statement, but the insertion into other.location doesn't include the event_id column (causing a ConstraintViolation on the not null). This would be because the Location doesn't have a reference to the Event object.

I cannot change the DB at all. I am using Hibernate 4. What do I do?

Here is all of the relevant configs:
Public Classes:

```
public class Event{
    private String eventId;
    private List<Location> locations;
    //getters & setters
}

public class Location{
    private String locationId;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Public Tables:

```
create table public.event{
    event_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    event_name varchar,
)

create table public.location(
    location_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
    event_id varchar NOT NULL, --foreign key to public.event.event_id
    lat double,
    lon double
)
```

public.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping schema="public">
    <class name="Event" table="event">
        <id name="eventId" column="event_id"/>
        <bag name="locations">
            <key column="event_id" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="Location">
        </bag>
    </class>
    <class name="Location" table="location">
        <id name="locationId" column="location_id"/>
        <property name="lat" column="lat"/>
        <property name="lon" column="lon"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Other Tables:

```
create table other.event inherits public.event(
    other_information varchar
)

create table other.location inherits public.location(
    other_loc_information varchar
)
```

Other Classes:

```
public class OtherEvent extends Event{
    private String otherInformation;
    //getter & setter
}

public class OtherLocation extends Location{
    private String otherLocInformation;
    //getter & setter
}
```

other.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping schema="other">
    <union-subclass name="OtherEvent" extends="Event" table="event">
        <property name="otherInformation" column="other_information"/>
    </union-subclass>
    <union-subclass name="OtherLocation" extends="Location" table="location">
        <property name="otherLocInformation" column="other_loc_information"/>
    </union-subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the solution is very close. You said:

> I cannot change the DB at all. I am using Hibernate 4. What do I do?

So I expect that you can change the code and mapping. If I am right and you can change the code and mapping: the setting `inverse` you've tried:

```
<bag name="locations" inverse="true">
```

should solve it. Only thing in this case is, that we also have to explicitly assign `Location` to `Event` (not only put it into owning collection).

`Location` should have a property `Event`

```
public class Location{
    private String locationId;
    private Event event;
    private double lat;
    private double lon;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The mapping should be:

```
<class name="Location" table="location">
  <id name="locationId" column="location_id"/>
  <property name="lat" column="lat"/>
  <property name="lon" column="lon"/>
  <many-to-one name="Event" column="event_id" />
</class>
```

So if in the code you will do:

```
event.locations.add(location);
location.event = event;
```

Then it should work with INSERTS only. The inverse means, that child will do all the stuff alone, so it has to know about parent.

Comment: Do you think the only way is to have the "child" (Location) know about the parent (Event)? That doesn't feel like a great solution, but if it works...

Comment: I would say, from my personal experience it is definitely correct solution. in `ORM` world, this is the most typical scenario (different form standard JAVA code, where often collection does not know the owner). But with Hibernate you will see that this is really normal and usual ;)